# Python reusing of module without new load

Tags: python, matlab

I have two modules, and I need to import one from another. In first module, I need to only declare variable and load (if its not loaded). In second, just read this variable and use that (if not loaded, in another module load it)

First module:

run_engine.py:

```
#run_engine.py
import matlab

eng = None

if(eng == None):
    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
```

start.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matlab.engine
import os
import run_engine

def app():
    currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    matlabInstance = run_engine.eng

    matlabInstance.addpath(currentDir)

    matlabInstance.sim('thermo_simple')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app()
```

matlab.engine.start_matlab takes about 30seconds to start, and i´m using start.py repeatly, so I need only one instance of eng, but correct loaded. How can I do that?

Comment: Some questions to code:
1) I assume there is something else in your code between statements eng = ... and if eng is ...? 2)    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab() # I assume that execution of this function takes 30 sec?`

Comment: 1. that was only about singleton, my assumption was, that i´ll run this code again and again and that long code (which you mention in 2) ) will be run only once. , so 2) you are right

Answer (score 0):

Run `app()` repeatedly in an interactive python shell:

```
$ python -i start.py
>>> app()
```

Comment: cant do that, because that script is not called from python shell

Answer (score 0):

```
#run_engine.py
import matlab
import time

eng = None

while not eng:
    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
    time.sleep(1)
```

BTW - if you want to use something like "if X == None" - this should be put as

```
if X is None
```

This is a preferable Python idiom ;)